# Query to remove "duplicate" rows using regexp

Tags: database, postgresql, unique-constraint

I am using PostgreSQL. I have a table `keywords`:

```
# Table name: keywords
#
#  id         :integer not null, primary key
#  text       :string  not null
#  match_type :string  not null
#  adgroup_id :integer not null
```

Table has a uniq index `USING btree (match_type, adgroup_id, text)`

Now, issue is that for same `adgroup_id` and `match_type` there are texts like `"Hello"` and `" Hello"` or `"Hello "` or `" Hello "` (note the leading/trailing whitespaces).
The issue is that `text` column contains those spaces in the beginning and end of string causing bad data (which would not have passed the uniq index without those whitespaces).

I am planning on adding a white-space trimming before insertion in the future, but first I need to clean up the data.

How do I remove the "duplicate" data leaving the unique ones (based on the string comparison *without* leading and trailing spaces)?

Comment: Are there any group with all elements containing white space? No "Hello" but only "Hello " and " Hello"?

Comment: @S-Man I am not sure I understood the question you've asked.  can be any option in db (with or without whitespaces). So there can be two rows of `"Hello"` and `" Hello"` and two rows of `"Hi"` and `"Hi "` and even, possibly, `" Hi"` and `"Hi "` (in which case I'd still have to leave one in DB in correct form (trimmed)

Comment: Ok added a more general solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2701925ec326f9d455cf352a3799da9d)
(example contains two groups: "Hello" without an element without whitespace; "Bye" contains two elements without whitespaces)

```
DELETE FROM keywords
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (trim(text))                 --1
        id
    FROM
        keywords
    ORDER BY 
        trim(text), 
        text = trim(text) DESC                   --2
)
```

1. Grouping on trimmed texts.
2. Order by trimmed texts and the information if the text is the one without whitespace. If there is one element then it will be ordered first and taken by the `DISTINCT ON` clause. If there is none another element will be taken

---

The solution containing the additional columns:

```
    DELETE FROM keywords
    WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (match_type, adgroup_id, trim(text))
            id
        FROM
            keywords
        ORDER BY 
            match_type,
            adgroup_id,
            trim(text), 
            text = trim(text) DESC
    )
```

Comment: @AndreyDeineko added the two missing columns from your example

Comment: the steps described sound exactly on point though I will take some time to understand the ordering magic and it relation to the DELETE statement. Big thanks for the help, upvoted!

Comment: Is this part `keyword = trim(text)` was supposed to be `text = trim(text)`?

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry, in my example I used another column name because "text" is a reserved name in Postgres and therefore not recommended for any further usage. To ensure your example I changed the column name here manually afterwards. I forgot this part :)

Comment: aah, see, we have flaws in our architecture including using reserved keyword.. thx again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option, using a CTE.  The CTE finds all `(match_type, adgroup_id)` groups having *two* or more `text` values which are identical with leading and trailing whitespace trimmed.  We also compute the following along the way:

- cnt - for each group, the number of times that the "pure" version of the text appears.  Pure here means that text with no leading or trailing whitespace
- rn - an arbitrary row number for each `(match_type, adgroup_id)` group, starting at value 1

We then delete a row only if it appears within a duplicate group and either it is not the pure version of text (`cnt > 0`), or the arbitrary row number is greater than one.  This means that for the case `"Hello "` and `" Hello"`, one of these two records would be arbitrarily deleted.  But, if there were a third "pure" record with `"Hello"`, then this would be retained and both of the previous two cased would be deleted.

```
with cte as (
    select match_type, adgroup_id, trim(text) as text,
        count(case when text = trim(text) then 1 end) as cnt,
        row_number() over (partition by match_type, adgroup_id order by trim(text)) rn
    from keywords
    group by match_type, adgroup_id, trim(text)
    having count(*) > 1
)

delete
from keywords k1
where exists (select 1 from cte k2
              where k1.match_type = k2.match_type and
                    k1.adgroup_id = k2.adgroup_id and
                    k1.text <> k2.text and (k2.cnt > 0 or k2.rn > 1));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! The description sounds just about right though I have one concern: how would this solution deal with `" Hello"` (leading) and `"Hello "` (trailing) given that in DB there is no "correct" version (`"Hello"`). Will it leave any of the two?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko It would have deleted both records.  I updated my answer so that in your example case, it would not delete either of the two records.  If you want to just end up with one `"Hello"` record (with no leading/trailing whitespace), then you are probably looking at a delete followed by an update or insert.

Comment: `I updated my answer so that in your example case, it would not delete either of the two records.` Can I ask you to revise it one last time to delete one of the two? So ultimately, leaving only one? In fact, we can remove all but one and then update to remove leading/trailing whitespaces in the remaining, uniq one.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! I've upvoted, now taking my time to learn how it works exactly

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I botched my use of row number.  Please try the updated answer.